# for f in $PWD subfolders

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, pwd

I'm running a script that verifies the integraty of a video file in my current folder. But only counts for my current folder and I want also to search files in the subfolders of $pwd.
What should I add in `$(ls $PWD/*.mp4)` ? 
Thank you

```
#!/bin/bash

# Verificação de Arquivos .MP4
echo Log Arquivos .MP4 >>Relatório.log

for f in $(ls $PWD/*.mp4)

do
    echo
    echo Verificando.mp4 $f
    echo >>Relatório.log
    ffmpeg -v error -i $f -f null - 2>>Relatório.log 

done
# FIM da Verificação de Arquivos .MP4
```

Comment: `ls` is for generating output for humans to read; it's not for use in scripts.

Comment: BTW, if your bash version is 4.0 or newer, consider `shopt -s globstar`, and then: `for f in "$PWD"/**/*.mp4; do`. The answers that use `find -print0` in the linked duplicate are also solid. Avoid anything that runs `find` inside `$()` syntax, or uses `find` without either `-print0` or `-exec`. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind for in-depth documentation.

Comment: Thank You. I'm new at coding and was really helpful :D